# Different coefficients of linear discriminants with the same raw data

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis, regression-coefficients

I have just tried two ways to perform a linear discriminant analysis.

**Mode 1**

This is the data, divided in two tables (printed from screen using R commander):
[image]
[image]

They belong respectively to the two already known groups.

I ran the next code to get the coefficients and critic value of the function:

```
m1=cov.wt(Craneos1)$center
m1=data.matrix(m1)
m2=cov.wt(Craneos2)$center
m2=data.matrix(m2)
D=((nrow(Craneos1)-1)*var(Craneos1)+(nrow(Craneos2)-1)*var(Craneos2))/30
d=solve(D)%*%(m1-m2)
d # Estos son los coeficientes de la función
0.5*t(m1+m2)%*%d # Este es el punto crítico
```

I get the next results:

```
> d # Coefficients of the discriminant analysis
           [,1]
x1 -0.089306662
x2  0.155774683
x3  0.005231617
x4 -0.177194601
x5 -0.177408670

> 0.5*t(m1+m2)%*%d # Este es el punto crítico
          [,1]
[1,] -30.46349
```

These results are exactly the same as those ones that appeared in a book I am studying.

**Mode 2**

I reordered the last two tables into only one with the first column as a factor:
[image]

In this case, I used the function **lda** (from the package MASS), since it has been widely used in examples on internet.

I ran the next command:

```
lda(group~.,data=Datos)
```

Which displayed the next results:

```
> lda(group~.,data=Datos)
Call:
lda(group ~ ., data = Datos)

Prior probabilities of groups:
CRANEOS1 CRANEOS2 
 0.53125  0.46875 

Group means:
               X1       X2       X3       X4       X5
CRANEOS1 174.8235 139.3529 132.0000 69.82353 130.3529
CRANEOS2 185.7333 138.7333 134.7667 76.46667 137.5000

Coefficients of linear discriminants:
            LD1
X1  0.047726591
X2 -0.083247929
X3 -0.002795841
X4  0.094695000
X5  0.094809401
```

My questions are:

Is there anything wrong in the code displayed above?

Why are the both coefficients different depending on the mode used?

Which of them must be more reliable?

How can I get the critic value using the Mode 2?

Comment: Looks like the coefficients are actually identical, up to a constant factor.

Comment: Actually, they seem to be the same. However they're not. I have also tried with different data and their values are clearly different, much wider than those ones exposed in this example...

Comment: They are identical, up to a constant factor `-1.8712`.

Comment: Oh, I see. And how can this difference be achieved comparing both methods?

Comment: The length of the discriminant vector is essentially arbitrary and does not matter. Perhaps your own algorithm and `lda()` function use different normalizations.

Comment: Thanks amoeba. Would you please, if you know, tell me which is the command to perform a prediction to determine which group would a particular specimen fit with following the Mode 2? For example, a specimen with the next numbers: X1=190, X2=150, X3=139, X4=79 and X5=142. Thanks

Comment: I am not an R user, so I don't really know, but according to what I read [in the 'MASS::lda' manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/lda.html), you should be using `predict` (see example in the end of the page).